# Making a new matrix from existing matrix

Tags: c, matlab, matrix

I am trying to write some code in **C** which gets the elements of an existing (made before) matrix  and make a new matrix from them. Imagine I have a matrix like `R[1][303]`, and I want to create a new matrix from it like `K[303 - n + 1][1]` which stores the elements of matrix `R` from its column `n` until its final column (i.e. column 303). I have a for loop on `n`, and the code I started to write is like:

```
  for (n=1; n<=201; n++)
  {
    float K[303-n+1][1]=????
  }
```

If I want to write it in Matlab, I would write:

```
  for n=1:201
  K=[];
  K(1:303-n+1,1)=R(n:end);
  end
```

but I have no idea how I have to write the part

```
  R(n:end)
```

in **C**. I appreciate if someone can give me a hint.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but have you read [Create C Source MEX-File](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html?nocookie=true)? If you have, you should be able to produce some kind of C code for it. You would then ask a question related to the section of code where you are stuck.

Comment: So you mean copy all columns from one matrix to rows of another matrix?

Comment: Your Matlab-Code does not make sense, you are assigning for example `K(1,1)` in every iteration.

Comment: Gopi, not all columns, in every iteration I want to copy the columns starting from n until the last column and make the rows of my new matrix (K) with them. So in every iteration the size of the new-made matrix changes, like k[302], K[301], K[300], ..., k [103].

Comment: You mean copy `n` columns from matrix `R` to `n` rows in matrix `K`, for each row in matrix `R` the equivalent column in matrix `K`?.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int R[1][10]={{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}};
int J[10][1];

//printf("ROW %d Column %d",sizeof(R)/sizeof(R[0]),sizeof(R[0])/sizeof(R[0][0]));
int i;

for(i=9; i >5; i--){
  J[i][0]=R[0][i];
}

for(i=6; i < 10; i++){
    printf("%d \n",J[i][0]);
}
return 0;
}
```